# Traversing back to the previous node using XPath in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, xpath, html-agility-pack

I have asked a question about [Traversing back to parent node in xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19460126/traversing-back-to-parent-node-in-xpath)

i got expected reply, however i have one more doubt with the further development. With below HTML:

```
<ul><li class="section">BROADCASTING</li>
<ul>
<li class="subsection"></li>
<li class="circle"><a href="/article/95242-STATION_BREAK.php">STATION BREAK</a></li>
<li class="circle"><a href="/article/98142-Labor_pains_hunger_pangs.php">Labor pains, hunger pangs</a></li>
<li class="circle"><a href="/article/101509-Wake_up_call_for_Dream_Team.php">Wake-up call for Dream Team</a></li>
<li class="circle"><a href="/article/136139-News_crew_turns_rescuer.php">News crew turns rescuer</a></li>
<li class="circle"><a href="/article/136140-Chopper_safety_had_been_challenged.php">Chopper safety had been challenged</a></li>
<li class="circle"><a href="/article/136142-Nielsen_adds_Dayton_.php">Nielsen adds Dayton..</a></li>
<li class="circle"><a href="/article/136143-Mondale_watch.php">Mondale watch</a></li>
<li class="circle"><a href="/article/136144-Those_70s_clearances.php">Those 70s clearances</a></li>
<li class="circle"><a href="/article/136145-Oscar_goes_to_ABC.php">Oscar goes to ABC</a></li>
<li class="circle"><a href="/article/136146-Hearst_Argyle_gives_a_green_light.php">Hearst-Argyle gives a green light</a></li>
<li class="circle"><a href="/article/136147-Finding_Geena_Davis.php">Finding Geena Davis</a></li>
<li class="circle"><a href="/article/136148-Syndication_Wrap_up.php">Syndication Wrap-up</a></li>
<li class="circle"><a href="/article/136149-CBS_TV_news_pioneer_dies_at_86.php">CBS TV news pioneer dies at 86</a></li>
<li class="circle"><a href="/article/136150-New_York_anchor_remembered.php">New York anchor remembered</a></li>
<li class="circle"><a href="/article/136151-News_sharing_in_West_Virginia.php">News sharing in West Virginia</a></li>
<li class="circle"><a href="/article/136152-News_dropping_in_Orlando.php">News dropping in Orlando</a></li>
<li class="subsection">Null</li>
<li class="circle"><a href="/article/136141-GET_WITH_THE_PROGRAM.php">GET WITH THE PROGRAM</a></li>
<li class="subsection">PEOPLE'S CHOICE</li>
<li class="circle"><a href="/article/97423-Syndication_as_branding.php">Syndication as branding</a></li>
</ul>
</ul>
```

with the help of **`@Alex`** now i can get all the sections and subsections. then i wanted the articles inside the subsection, i tried that myself and received expected output, however my problem is now after the `<li class="subsection">` tag we have individual `<li class="circle">` tag which contains the information of the article inside `anchor` tag, now as the `class="circle"` tag is itself the individual node (not inside the `class="subsection"` node), i cannot just gets article inside the particular subsection, it fetches all the articles in first subsection and then, in second sub-section it also fetches the articles from the third sub-section, it only works fine in the last sub-section as it does not have any more sub-sections.

Can anyone tell me how shall i limit the articles within the particular sub-section, i mean when it gets the `class="subsection"` tag, it should stop fetching for articles further for that subsection, and start fetching for another sub-section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like:

`//ul/ul[preceding::li[@class='section' and .=\"BROADCASTING\"]]/li[@class='subsection' and .=\"\"]/following::li[@class='circle' and following::li[@class='subsection' and .=\"Null\"]]/a`

to get all the anchors between `<li class='subsection'></li>` and `<li class='subsection'>Null</li>`. To get links between `<li class='subsection'>Null</li>` and `<li class='subsection'>PEOPLE'S CHOICE</li>` you need to replace necessary values here: `li[@class='subsection' and .=\"{...}\"`.

To get anchors under the last subsection, the next expression will be enough:
`//ul/ul[preceding::li[@class='section' and .=\"BROADCASTING\"]]/li[@class='subsection' and .=\"PEOPLE'S CHOICE\"]/following::li[@class='circle']/a"`.

I hope you've caught the idea.

Comment: HI @Alex the ditto thing i have did, but the problem is when i specify
/li[@class='subsection' and .=\"PEOPLE'S CHOICE\"], but it does not works, from second subsection it still takes an article and append it to the first one.

Comment: @Abbas: could you please specify where exactly you experienced a problem: first, second or third subsection?

Comment: Hi @Alex, first of all, thanks for being so kind to revert back and giving your valuable help at every step, actually if i use above method, My First Subsection (<li class="subsection"></li>) fetches all the article underneath, however it does not stops when it finds another (<li class="subsection">Null</li>) instead it still go inside the second subsection and fetches the first article.

Comment: @Abbas, to get the first subsection you need the first expression from the answer. See, I created a code snippet [here](http://pastebin.com/uMksQuy8). It selects *exactly* 16 anchors from the first subsection. Nothing more.

Comment: Actually you have catched the next sub-section name to avoid catching next sub-section's article, but while programming, i cannot have the name of the next sub-section, until i execute the sub-section, which will be after executing all the anchors in the first sub-section.

Comment: @Abbas, in this case it will be much easier to utilize LINQ instead of xpath here.